# sqlite - get all entries from today

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, unix-timestamp

I have an android app with sqlite database which has a column holding the entry creation date in **unix-time format** (`DateTime().getMillis() / 1000`).

What I want is very simple, to get all the entries from today.

Just to be clear, I mean all entries bigger than at 00:00:00 of today (just after midnight of yesterday).

I guess my timezone should also go in the query somewhere, because unix-time is in UTC.

Comment: do you know sql's `BETWEEN`?

Comment: I really don't understand why all the down votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Unix timestamp can be computed with:

```sql
strftime('%s', 'now')
```

To go to the start of the day, add a [modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of day')
```

However, this uses 00:00:00 in the UTC timezone, so you have to convert the timestamp to the local time zone, go to *that* start of the date, and convert it back:

```sql
strftime('%s', 'now', 'localtime', 'start of day', 'utc')
```

And `strftime` returns a string, so you should convert its result into a number:

```sql
... WHERE EntryCreationDate >= 0 + strftime(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
String sql=<b>"SELECT * FROM water_intake where my_date >= date('now', 'localtime')";
cursor = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

This is for getting all the today's data from table(water_intake) where `my_dat`e is the column of Date in my database.
`localtime` I have seen somewhere so I have tried and getting all the today's data which I have wanted.

Answer (score -1):

```
String sql = "SELECT * from Table1 where myDate = (select max(myDate) from Table1 WHERE myDate < DATE('now') )";
Cursor mycursor = db.rawQuery(sql);
```

I am not sure just check this once, it may works!

Answer (score -2):

Please check this code

WHERE CurrentDate BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+1 day')